# Selenium HTMLDriver not working but Firefox Driver is ok

Tags: java, selenium

So I have a very simple test script written by Selenium. When I have:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

my test will run fine.

But this does not work:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
```

It says:

```
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:912)
at com.innflow.ebtam.selenium.HelloSelenium.main(HelloSelenium.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

why?

Enabling javascript on HtmlUnitDriver changes nothing.

Comment: I've had poor luck with `HtmlUnitDriver` as well.. i'm also curious to know the answer to this. +1

Comment: From my experience, HtmlUnitDriver has extremely poor AJAX support. Try PhantomJSDriver instead.